# Display each label in labeled & segmented image in R

Tags: r, label, each, display

Labeled and segmented image in: http://postimg.org/image/l9ckw4g61/

Number of labels in the above image (using 'max' command): 27.

I want to display one label (or connected component) at a time in the image:

something like in the below 'for'

```
for(eachlabel in 1:max(labeled_segmented)){

  # Show me one label out of 27 each time
}
```

How can I achieve this in R programming?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Bioconductor package **EBImage** you could try something like

```
for(label in 1:max(labeled_segmented)) {
  display(labeled_segmented==label) 
}
```

Or try the function `colorLabels` to display all objects at once but each one colored differently.